# Android Studio Emulator Stopped Working on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am VERY new to Android Studio. I'm teaching myself the basics to build my first app via a number of online courses. After 4 months of Java study I finally have begun to take on Android and then my emulator suddenly stopped working.

With a simple "Hello World" app, the emulator will not run. In the Emulator section it states: "Emulator: No running emulators."

In the Run Log it states: "Launching 'app' on No Devices. Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for.... was killed."

The Event Log always states: "Gradle build finished in ### ms."

My Mac has 32 GBs of memory. There are no other programs running beyond Safari. I'm using only about 10% of 998 GB of storage.

I ran a Memory Use Report and it stated Android Studio was using an unusually high memory use...why I don't understand.

I have tried all of the following numerous times:

- Re-installed Android Studio
- Restarted my Mac
- Deleted all the Virtual Devices
- Made new Virtual Devices
- Cold Boot
- Wipe Data
- Reduced Ram of Virtual Device
- Restored Default settings of Android Studio
- Virtual Device Graphics Automatic, Hardware and Software
- Sync project with Grade
- Etc.

I get the same errors no matter which setting I change. No running emulator and the emulator gets killed. It has been two days I can't continue with my course with no emulator. Hope someone out there can assist and help get me back on track. Thanks!

Per Response:

- Mac Version: High Sierra 10.13.6
- Android Studio Version: 4.1.2
- Mac: iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch 2017) Processor 3 GHz Intel Core i5

Screen Captures:

- Tested with with Kotlin hello world app:
  [Output Image Example from Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kjcT.jpg)

Per This Suggestion:
Please update with log of starting emulator via command line: developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

I got this output:[Command Line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIabt.png) ...not sure what this means. I am reading further into it. Thanks.

- Virtual Device SetUp:
  [Virtual Device SetUp Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3LBH.png)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66698235/edit) your post to include: which model of Mac, which MacOS version, which version of Android Studio.

Comment: This all is useless, unless adding console output of the emulator startup.

Comment: Please update with log of starting emulator via command line: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline